# A flexible list with indefinite number of nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I am supposed to make a linked list that takes in strings and prints them out in the reverse order. Normally I'd ask the number of nodes that need to be created, and then ask for the data in a for loop until we're done.

```
typedef struct word_st {
   string word; // string is meant to be a pointer to a struct
   word_st *next;
 }
```

But the problem is, the number of nodes isn't known until runtime. So I have to keep asking for data until the user is done. I'm not really sure where to start/how to do that and can't seem to find anything on the internet either. So a hint would be very helpful.

I have my insert function and the print function looks fairly simple too.

```
    word_t *insert_2(word_t* head, string text) {
    word_t * p = NULL;
    word_t * temp = (word_t*) malloc(sizeof(word_t));

    temp -> word = text;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL) {
      head = temp;
    } else {
      p = head;
    } while(p -> next != NULL) {
      p = p -> next;
    }
    p -> next = temp;
   return head;
   }
```

Comment: Just call the insertion function in a loop until the input ends? I'm not really sure about what problems you have, can you please elaborate?

Comment: And if you want to reverse the "input", then use the list as a *stack*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought about putting the insertion in a loop but I still need an expression for the loop so that the compiler knows that the input has ended. And I can't really figure that out!

Comment: Your `insert_2` function adds the string to the back of the list. It would make more sense to add the string to the front of the list since that would put them in reverse order as required.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The number of nodes isn't known until the user is done typing so I can't go for a simple while(i <n).. I am having a hard time figuring that out

Comment: There are two ways to handle end-of-input: End of file (`EOF`); Or an end of input sentinel (special string or value denoting the end). First pick one of the methods, and the loop condition will follow from that.

Comment: What are you using to read the input strings from the user? Note that each string will need to be stored in its own dynamically allocated buffer. The thing that reads the strings into a buffer can return `NULL` to indicate that the end of file was reached. If input is from a terminal, there should be a way for the user to indicate end of file, e.g. using Ctrl-D on Linux/Mac or Ctrl-Z on Windows.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh okay, I'm not sure how they work so I guess I'll look them up right away. In the meantime, can you tell me what the conditions in one of them looks like? So I at least have a rough idea. or a link to some thread would be really helpful too.

Comment: @IanAbbott So far I've created a temporary char* and allocated memory for it and I am simply using scanf to read the string

Comment: "Normally I'd ask the number of nodes that need to be created, and then ask for the data...". That's very inconvenient for anyone entering the data. Computers are way better at counting things than people are. People just want to type their data and then indicate that they are finished. So you should get into the habit of writing input loops which accommodate that behaviour: keep reading until you get an indication that the user is done. If the "I'm done" signal is to close the input stream by typing the end-of-input character, then you stop when `scanf` returns `EOF`.

Comment: @rici thank you, that seems much simpler but I am not fully sure how to write *EOF* that in C!

Comment: It's written `EOF`. See the documentation for [`scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE), particularly the section on return values.

Comment: @rici Thank You, I'll have a look at it right away. I was actually meant to say that I 'm not sure how I'd implement that in a loop. I know that the loop is supposed to run until the scanf returns EOF, but what I don't know is - how to code that. But I'll read the documentation or look up an example or something!

Comment: @dean: maybe you need to review C loops, particularly the `do … while()` statement. (Or `break`, but that's always second best.)

Comment: @rici thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1):

In reverse, replace **next** by **prev**:

```
typedef struct word_st {
    string word; // string is meant to be a pointer to a struct
    word_st * prev;
}
```

*And the function:*

```
word_t *insert_2(word_t* head, string text) {
    word_t * nextHead = (word_t*) malloc(sizeof(word_t));
    nextHead -> word = text;
    nextHead -> prev = NULL;

    // Check first element of LIFO 
    if( head == NULL ) {
        return nextHead;
    }

    nextHead -> prev = head;
    return nextHead;
}
```

I hope It compiles and work.

Note:

```
for(word_t * head = last ; head->prev != NULL ; head = head->prev )
{
    // Do the job
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, one question though. what's last in *word_t *head = last *supposed to be?

Comment: It's the lastest result when  you call insert2(..);